# KML polygon crossing 180th/anti-mederian

Tags: polygon, kml, google-earth, simplekml

I'm using *simplekml* to try and generate a KML polygon around lat=0, long=180 (anti-mederian).  How to fix this KML so it's displayed correctly in Google Earth?  It currently wraps around the earth the "wrong" way; not sure why.

[image: Screenshot]

KML source:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <Style id="6">
            <LineStyle id="7">
                <color>ff008000</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <width>0</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle id="8">
                <color>64008000</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark id="3">
            <name>test</name>
            <description>test</description>
            <styleUrl>#6</styleUrl>
            <Polygon id="2">
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing id="4">
                        <coordinates>-178.5,2.5,0.0 176.5,2.5,0.0 176.5,-2.5,0.0 -178.5,-2.5,0.0 -178.5,2.5,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Google Earth Screenshot of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay48m.png

Comment: Years ago I had to split dateline-straddling polygons into multi-part polygons, because Google Earth didn't like 175.5-185.5 longitude rectangles.

Comment: Seems like a Google Earth problem.  That KML works in the Google Maps API v3, doesn't work in Google Earth.

Comment: It's a Google Earth problem, affects raster overlays too ~ https://onegeology.org/images/wmsCookbook/GE-hole-500.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try using values over 180 (or below -180).  While it's not great practice, it does work in Earth Pro.

If you try manually drawing a polygon across the anti-meridian, and look at the KML it produces (copy/paste the feature into a text editor), you'll see that it uses values above 180.

Below is a copy of your KML where the three instances of "-178.5" longitude values have been replaced with the equivalent "181.5", and it seems to work for me.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <Style id="6">
            <LineStyle id="7">
                <color>ff008000</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <width>0</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle id="8">
                <color>64008000</color>
                <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark id="3">
            <name>test</name>
            <description>test</description>
            <styleUrl>#6</styleUrl>
            <Polygon id="2">
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing id="4">
                        <coordinates>181.5,2.5,0.0 176.5,2.5,0.0 176.5,-2.5,0.0 181.5,-2.5,0.0 181.5,2.5,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```